# filter_interface = models.HORIZONTAL --- 'module' object has no attribute 'HORIZONTAL'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I keep getting the error:

> 'module' object has no attribute 'HORIZONTAL'

Some of my models are defined with `filter_interface = models.HORIZONTAL`.

What is `filter_interface = models.HORIZONTAL` and why am I missing this attribute?

More information: The code was written for version '0.97-pre-SVN-unknown'

and I am using version '1.4.1'

Maybe this error is because I am using a newer version of django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter parameters are not specified on the models, but on the `ModelAdmin` objects.  Without delving into the 0.97 code base, I suspect that the interface has changed.  Filtering is part of the `django.contrib.admin` application so I'd recommend to read the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/.

You may have to refactor the`filter_interface` parameter to use the [`ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) attribute.